# How to get url of uploaded file to google drive in android using Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I need to get the link of the video that I upload it to google drive so that I can open the video in the web browser, I can upload a video file to google drive and can get also the file ID using the following code:

```
private void UploadFile(final DriveId driveId)
{
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult)
        {
            if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess())
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error while trying to create new file contents");
                return;
            }
            OutputStream outputStream = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Uploading to drive....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final File theFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/VideoFiles/testVideo.mkv");
            try
            {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(theFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } catch (IOException e1)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
            }
            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setTitle(theFile.getName()).setMimeType("video/mkv").setStarred(false).build();
            DriveFolder folder = driveId.asDriveFolder();
            folder.createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContentsResult.getDriveContents()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull DriveFolder.DriveFileResult driveFileResult)
                        {
                            if (!driveFileResult.getStatus().isSuccess())
                            {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Error while trying to create the file");
                                return;
                            }
                            Log.v(TAG, "Created a file: " + driveFileResult.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

I tried to get the video url using the following code:

```
DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(googleApiClient,driveId);
                            DriveResource.MetadataResult mdRslt = file.getMetadata(googleApiClient).await();
                            if (mdRslt != null && mdRslt.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                String link = mdRslt.getMetadata().getWebContentLink();
                                Log.d("LINK", link);
                            }
```

But then I got "Cannot resolve symbol 'googleApiClient'
Any suggestion please?

Comment: This is because `googleApiClient` is not defined. You should be using `mGoogleApiClient` like you have everywhere else in you code.

Comment: Thanks for replay, however I noticed that the file ID that  I got from driveFileResult.getDriveFile().getDriveId() is not completed: "DriveId:CAESABiwayCK16yy6VAoAA==" that is strange for me? If I have it correct then I can build the url by adding some string started with https://drive.google.com/......File ID.....

Comment: here's a clue. Your code says "Uploading to drive....", but you are using GDAA so you are NOT uploading to Drive. All you are doing is saving the file locally. Some time later, Play Services will sync your file to Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution, first I have to get the completed file ID by using the change events listener, then we can add "drive.google.com/open?id=" to the file ID, so the complate url will be drive.google.com/open?id=FileID.
here is my answer:

```
public class Uploader extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener{
private static final String TAG = "Google Drive Activity";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;
private static final  int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 2;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public DriveFile file;
private String FOLDER_NAME = "GD_VideoFile";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {

        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        return;
    }

    try {

        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);

    } catch (SendIntentException e) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
    {
        check_folder_exists();
    } else
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not connect to google drive manager");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
                                final int resultCode, final Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                DriveId mFileId = data.getParcelableExtra(
                        OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                Log.e("file id", mFileId.getResourceId() + "");
                String url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id="+ mFileId.getResourceId();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            break;
    }
}

private void check_folder_exists()
{
    Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.and(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, FOLDER_NAME), Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false))).build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result)
        {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess())
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Cannot create folder in the root.");
            } else
            {
                boolean isFound = false;
                for (Metadata m : result.getMetadataBuffer())
                {
                    if (m.getTitle().equals(FOLDER_NAME)) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Folder exists");
                        isFound = true;
                        DriveId driveId = m.getDriveId();
                        UploadFile(driveId);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isFound)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Folder not found; creating it.");
                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setTitle(FOLDER_NAME).build();
                    Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                            .createFolder(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet)
                            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResult(@NonNull DriveFolder.DriveFolderResult result)
                                {
                                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess())
                                    {
                                        Log.e(TAG, "Error while trying to create the folder");
                                    } else {
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Created a folder");
                                        DriveId driveId = result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId();
                                        UploadFile(driveId);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


private void UploadFile(final DriveId driveId)
{

    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult)
        {
            if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess())
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "U AR A MORON! Error while trying to create new file contents");
                return;
            }

            OutputStream outputStream = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
            Toast.makeText(Uploader.this, "Uploading to drive....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final File theFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyMobile_Videos/a.mov");
            try
            {
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(theFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
                {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } catch (IOException e1)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
            }

            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setTitle(theFile.getName()).setMimeType("video/mov").setStarred(false).build();
            DriveFolder folder = driveId.asDriveFolder();
            folder.createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContentsResult.getDriveContents()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>()
            {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull DriveFolder.DriveFileResult driveFileResult)
                        {
                            if (!driveFileResult.getStatus().isSuccess())
                            {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Error while trying to create the file");
                                return;
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(Uploader.this, "Created a file: " + driveFileResult.getDriveFile().getDriveId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String Folder_Id = driveId.getResourceId();
                            System.out.println("The folder id: " +Folder_Id);

                            //This is to get the file id from the listener
                            DriveId File_Uncompleted_Id = driveFileResult.getDriveFile().getDriveId();
                            DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, File_Uncompleted_Id);
                            file.addChangeListener(mGoogleApiClient, changeListener);
                        }

                //A listener to handle file change events.
                final private ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event)
                    {
                        String File_Completed_Id =  event.getDriveId().getResourceId();
                        System.out.println("The uploaded file id: " +File_Completed_Id);
                        System.out.println("File URL: https://drive.google.com/open?id=" +File_Completed_Id);

                    }
                };
            }
                    );
        }

    }
    );
}
```

}